# Making the Alphabet scroll listview height dynamic when using the single child scroll view causing issue for list while scroll

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently I am working on the feature that shows the list with alphabet scroll list where i a have used the following package

```
https://pub.dev/packages/azlistview
```

So the Issue is If i use the AzListView (from package) in the single child scroll view it does not scale gives the render error. Can any one suggest what can be done in order to make work.
I have added the sample code from what i have done.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:azlistview/azlistview.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ContactsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ContactsPageState createState() => _ContactsPageState();
}

class _ContactsPageState extends State<ContactsPage> {
  List<ContactInfo> contactList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }

  void loadData() async {
    List list = json.decode(stringData);
    for (var v in list) {
      contactList.add(ContactInfo.fromJson(v));
    }
    _handleList(contactList);
  }

  void _handleList(List<ContactInfo> list) {
    if (list.isEmpty) return;
    for (int i = 0, length = list.length; i < length; i++) {
      String tag = list[i].name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
      list[i].namePinyin = list[i].name;
      if (RegExp("[A-Z]").hasMatch(tag)) {
        list[i].tagIndex = tag;
      } else {
        list[i].tagIndex = "#";
      }
    }
    // A-Z sort.
    SuspensionUtil.sortListBySuspensionTag(contactList);

    // show sus tag.
    SuspensionUtil.setShowSuspensionStatus(contactList);

    setState(() {});
  }

  static Widget getWeChatListItem(
    BuildContext context,
    ContactInfo model, {
    double susHeight = 40,
    Color? defHeaderBgColor,
  }) {
    return getWeChatItem(context, model, defHeaderBgColor: defHeaderBgColor);
  }

  static String getImgPath(String name, {String format: 'png'}) {
    return 'assets/images/$name.$format';
  }

  static Widget getWeChatItem(
    BuildContext context,
    ContactInfo model, {
    Color? defHeaderBgColor,
  }) {
    DecorationImage? image;
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Container(
          width: 36,
          height: 36,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
            color: model.bgColor ?? defHeaderBgColor,
            image: image,
          ),
          child: model.iconData == null
              ? null
              : Icon(
                  model.iconData,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 20,
                ),
        ),
        title: Text(model.name),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFEDEDED),
        title: const Text(
          'List items',
          style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF171717)),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Text('Sample'),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Next Page')),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: AzListView(
                data: contactList,
                itemCount: contactList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  ContactInfo model = contactList[index];
                  return getWeChatListItem(
                    context,
                    model,
                    defHeaderBgColor: const Color(0xFFE5E5E5),
                  );
                },
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                indexBarData: SuspensionUtil.getTagIndexList(contactList),
                indexBarOptions: IndexBarOptions(
                  needRebuild: true,
                  ignoreDragCancel: true,
                  downTextStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white),
                  downItemDecoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.green),
                  indexHintWidth: 120 / 2,
                  indexHintHeight: 100 / 2,
                  indexHintDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage(getImgPath('ic_index_bar_bubble_gray')),
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                  ),
                  indexHintAlignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  indexHintChildAlignment: const Alignment(-0.25, 0.0),
                  indexHintOffset: const Offset(-20, 0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final String stringData = '''[
  {
    "name": "Alice",
    "phone": [
      "18221338086"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Stacy",
    "phone": [
      "18221338086"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Bob",
    "phone": [
      "18221338086"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "David",
    "phone": [
      "18221338086"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Jenny",
    "phone": [
      "18221338086"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Zara",
    "phone": [
      "18221338086"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Milly",
    "phone": [
      "18221338086"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Yasmin",
    "phone": [
      "18221338086"
    ]
  }
]
''';

class ContactInfo extends ISuspensionBean {
  String name;
  String? tagIndex;
  String? namePinyin;

  Color? bgColor;
  IconData? iconData;

  String? img;
  String? id;
  String? firstletter;

  ContactInfo({
    required this.name,
    this.tagIndex,
    this.namePinyin,
    this.bgColor,
    this.iconData,
    this.img,
    this.id,
    this.firstletter,
  });

  ContactInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        img = json['img'],
        id = json['id']?.toString(),
        firstletter = json['firstletter'];

  @override
  String getSuspensionTag() => tagIndex!;

  @override
  String toString() => json.encode(this);
}
```

I know if we give static height to the widget it works. But i do not want it.

From the suggestions i have made some changes anding a GIF below for where i am having issue.

[image]

I have added the shrinkwrap=true inside the plugin and then neverscrolphysices for the list. But now it has wired behaviour.

I will add a Git repo in some time for the complete code that i have done.

Check out the complete code in below mentioned repo:
https://github.com/sagaracharya24/AZScrollList.git

Comment: How about using parent scroll and not have separate scroll on Az list? Can you include an gif you are trying to get

Comment: I tried it but alphabet on the right require the list to be scrollable. I will add the image in some time

Comment: consider including gif or images that clarify the scroll behavior as well the view port

Comment: Hey @YeasinSheikh I have added the image as well as the repo for the code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is AZList view already has a scroll. And a single child scrollview  also has the scroll.. Add Neverscrollable physics to AZListView like

Remove expanded. This will try creating a widget with no bounds

Add shrinkwrap

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
   children: [
   //OtherWidgets here
     AzListView(
       shrinkWrap: true,
       physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),//here
     
   )
  ]
 )
)
```

Comment: I get your point but the class is of the plugin. And even if we add the shrin wrap to true the scroll that we do for alphabet is messing up

Comment: Did you add the physics too?

Comment: Let me check again

Comment: Hey I have added the repo for the complete code.

Comment: Did it work as expected? You can remove the Expanded widget too.

Comment: No removing the expanded does not work for me have added the latest code in the Git repo.

Comment: If we add a shrinkwrap to true the then the list has a glich while scrolling added in the GIF

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is the last element of list need to be on top of screen while changing from sorting .

Comment: It seems there is the spaces added when scrolling in the list, if we add the shrink wrap  to true.

Comment: Okay so you need to element to top not in between spaces right?

Comment: yes i want it to scroll properly.